# Android Emulator and Genymotion Emulator opens but cannot deploy my Application

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, genymotion

When I try to use "Deploy" to deploy my app to any Android emulator or genymotion emulator, the emulator opens, but the deployment does not start.  I've waited up to 15 minutes. What do I need to look into in order to get this deployment to work successfully? I also tried using genymotion but nothing shows up.

Comment: Please check the logs inside RUN tab at the bottom. And see whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

check your gradle build if it was successful